# Where are the monero-core configuration parameters stored?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Where are the monero-core (official GUI) configuration values stored?

Answer (score 15):

The monero-core configuration is stored in the following places:

Linux (File) :

```
/home/xxx/.config/The Monero Project/monero-core.conf
```

Windows (registry key) :

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\The Monero Project\monero-core
```

OS-X (File) :

```
$HOME/Library/Preferences/org.getmonero.monero-core.plist
```

Comment: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\monero-project\monero-core for me on windows

Answer (score 4):

OS X: $HOME/Library/Preferences/org.getmonero.monero-core.plist

Answer (score 0):

New location as at 2023-12-25 on Windows 11:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\monero-project